# Error code E000001 on Canon Image Runner 2525 printer

Tags: printer

My Canon Image Runner 2525 printer displays this message:

> Turn the main power switch (On the main unit left side) OFF and ON again.
>   Error code E000001

I tried to turn OFF and ON, but the problem persists.

Comment: Yea... maybe you should call technical help up for Canon. This sounds like an internal error, coudl be anything like, RAM fault, FW fault, bay fault, alignment strip fault, or paper sensor error, or drum error, cartridge error, voltage supply error....

Answer (score 1):

According to some Canon forums, this may be caused by over-heating. Perhaps turning it off and waiting for about 1/2 hour will help. If that does not help, the guys in the forum strongly recommend to call the canon tech support.

Comment: Oh yea.. So its most liekly going to be the heat sensor error reporting overheating the whole time. So most likely you will need to call Canon to replace/fix it..